# What could be causing a 500 error on some branches in gitlab project repo commit history?

Tags: gitlab

On gitlab.com, when I go to the commit history page for a particular branch, I get a 500 error. On a different branch in the same repo, it works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: There's a (very large) number of reasons a 500 error like this can occur. Without more information, in order to tell what the problem is, you would have to look at the server logs. Unfortunately, for GitLab.com, customers do not have access to those logs. Therefore, your only option would be to put in a support request to GitLab to determine the cause of this error.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thanks @sytech, this helps me move forward. Much appreciated!